# Can we use IoTConnect for UI SDK instead of API call in Application

Tags: iot, iotconnect

**IoTConnect** Provide UI SDK and API Methods to communication with the IoT Platform. both methods is working same, which one do I need to use for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, SDK is more powerful and better solution then APIs. 
APIs have a static baseURL and fixed input pramas. If APIs owner changes the baseUrl pattern or input or output params then it won't work. You need to set again baseUrl and check one by one parmas to get the result

In SDK, you just need to update the SDK library and check the documentation for updated params only. It will easy to reconfigure compare to APIs.

I suggest go ahead with SDK to ease of use and more scalable.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, use can use any of the method UI SDK or API call to communication with your application. I suggest to go with SDK because it's easy to manage compare to API calls. Based on the Best practice document of IoTConnect on https://help.iotconnect.io, They are recommended to use SDK.

Currently they provide limited language in UI SDK, so please check your development language is listed on the document for SDK.